# Add invalid entity to Entity Framework context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Let's follow given scenario:

1. `DbContext` is injected into my class using Unity container
2. I create a new entity with invalid data and add it to the context
3. then I do `SaveChanges` on context
4. I get an exception - OK
5. then I want to add valid entity to `dbContext`
6. I get an exception because of the first invalid entity that I don't want to save now.

What is the best solution to support this kind of situations? How to deal with injected context lifetime while my class (which uses this context) lives for the whole app lifetime?

I'm using EF 6

THis is pseudocode, please remember that Im using Unity dependency injection container:

```
public class Test
    {
        //this class contains dbContext
        private IMyRepository _repository;

        public Test(IMyRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public AddEntity(MyEntity test)
        {
            _repository.AddEntity(test);
            try
            {
                //here exception may occur and from this point Im unable to save anything    
                _repository.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //I need to do this in order to not get exception next time I try to save
                _repository.Remove(test);
            }

        }

    }

    public class MyRepository
    {
        private readonly IModelContext _context; // DBContext
        public MyRepository(IModelContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Just remove that invalid entity before calling  `SaveChanges` the second time ....

Comment: the `DbContext` is a unit of work. After the first `SaveChanged` you should not reuse it for subsequent changes. So you should configure your `IoC container` that it provides you with a new `DbContext` each time.

Comment: SOunds great but how to do this :/

Comment: Could you show us your problem code.

Comment: How do you **add** it? `SomeDbSet.Add(entity)`? Just call `SomeDbSet.Remove(entity)` again to remove it when an error occurs.....

Comment: I added sample classes to show you how its done right now